# Get All elements in between two elements in Array

Tags: c#, arrays, element

I have a Array in c#.

```
public string[] alphabet = new string[] { "A","B","C",.......}
```

I want to return each and every elements which between two mentioned element.

Ex:

```
I want to return all elements in between "A" and "D". It should return {A,B,C,D} as result.
```

How can I do this? Is there any build in support or Are we suppose to write our own? Please help me.

Comment: Are your array elements always sorted?

Comment: Yes. It is a Static container which contain Eng Alphabet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`GetRange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getrange?view=net-6.0):

```
alphabetList = alphabet.ToList();
string[] range = (alphabetList.GetRange(alphabetList.IndexOf("A"), alphabetList.IndexOf("D") + 1)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

If its only about Alphabet array then we can call a loop and then cast its variable to char.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fist = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, "A");
var second = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, "D");
var newArray = alphabet.Skip(fist).Take(second - fist + 1).ToArray();
```

OR

```
var newArray2 = alphabet.ToList().GetRange(fist, second - fist + 1).ToArray();
```